# Tailwind CSS installed in react (vite) but not working

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

[This is the image after installing Vite and Tailwind css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDQTW.png)

[tailwind.congif.js code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLmSC.png)

in Index css I tried as mentioned in Tailwind as below

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

But not working.

I saw in YouTube videos once they installed tailwind css and entered css code Hover is coming in VS code. But for me its not coming. Even I deleted unwanted CSS codes in App.css and Index.css. Yet not working.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hover css popover is a feature of the [Tailwind CSS IntelliSense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss) extension in VSCode. To install it, you can click on the `Install` button in the link or in VS Code Extension manager by:

1. Open VS Code
2. In the left sidebar (if it's not there, enable it in `View > Appearance > Activity Bar`), select the Extension icon and search for `Tailwind CSS IntelliSense`.
3. Install it by clicking on the blue `Install` button.

Now you can hover over the tailwind classes to see the corresponding CSS code.

Have a nice day!

PS: After installing it, you'll see it is displayed as the picture below

[image: VS Code left sidebar]

Comment: No problem. Just one favor, could you please mark my answer as accepted and upvote it. I'm building my profile, it would help a lot. Many thanks!

Comment: Sure Bro. I'm new to Stack overflow. Till I need 2 points for reputation to upvote it. But now I accepted it bro.